# sum between tables with difficulty

Tags: python, odoo

I want to make a ledger, therefore I need first of all to add the debit and have each account entered.

I have two tables called "Account" and "detail_document". In the "account" table I have fields.Char which has the function of writing the name of the account, and in the "document_detail" I have an attribute called "input_value", "output_value".

The input value is the purchase price of each product, and in "output_value" is the price of each product ", then with those attributes, I need to add them and add it to the corresponding account.

For example:

A screw has a final purchase value of $ 2 (which would be the debit) and a final sale value of $ 4 (which would be the credit), and both are in the "Cash" account. Another person or the same person has a screwdriver that has a purchase price of $ 3 (must) and a sale price of ($ 6). With this data, it should appear on the computer created total value must = $ 8 and have $ 10 in the "cash" account

I hope that it has been understood and here I leave the code and the method that I try to do.

```
class Account (models.Model):
    _name = 'project_rc.account'

    name = fields.Char (string = "Name")
    total_account_must = fields.Float (string = "Total account must", compute = "_total_account_must")
    total_account_credit = fields.Float (string = "Total account credit", compute = "_total_account_credit")
    document_document_ids = fields.One2many (as del_name = 'project_rc.detail_document', inverse_name = 'account_id', string = 'Document detail',required = True)


    @ api.one
    @ api.depends (detail_document_ids)
    def _total_account_must(self):
        sum = 0
        if self.title == "Cash":
            for detail_document in self.detail_document_ids:
                 sum + = detail_document.total_must
                 self.total_account_must = sum

class Document_Detail (models.Model):
    _name = 'project_rc.detail_document'

   total_must = fields.Float (string = "Input value")
   total_credit = fields.Float (string = "Output value")
   account_id = fields.Many2one (comodel_name = 'project_rc.account', string = 'Account')
```

Comment: help me please...

Comment: Just an idea to make it easier, having debits be negative, and credits positive and then simply filtering all negative values summing them (total debit), and repeating the same for positive values (total credit)?

Comment: I just want to add everything that is added to the total attribute owed in the cash account. I attached an image with an example that I want to get so that I can understand better. You can let me know if you understand what I am saying please because your help is of utmost importance. link: https://ibb.co/hWM44Hj